# ObservableArray only updating UI after Remove

Tags: knockout.js

I seem to have stumbled into an interesting anomoly with KnockoutJS.

I have an object with an ko.obseravableArray in it.

I can programmatically, before I apply bindings add items to the array. When the UI updates it looks correct.  Then when I click on a button to add an item to the array it appears as if nothing has happened.  However, when I remove an item from the array the UI then updates.

```
 var Feature = function (desription, price)
 {
    var self = this;

    var _description = desription;
    self.description = ko.observable(_description);

    var _price = price;
    self.price = ko.observable(_price);
}

var ItemFeature = function(feature) 
 {
    var self = this;

    var _feature = feature;
    self.feature = ko.observable(_feature);
}

var Item = function ()
{
    var self = this;

    self.featuresList = [
    new Feature("Feature 1", 1.50),
    new Feature("Feature 2", 2.00)
    ];

    self.features = ko.observableArray();

    self.addNewFeature = function () {
        self.features().push(new ItemFeature(self.featuresList[0]));
    }

    self.removeFeature = function (sender) {
        self.features.remove(sender);
    }
}

var _viewModel = new Item();
_viewModel.addNewFeature();
ko.applyBindings(_viewModel);
```

And the markup:

```
 <table>
            <thead><tr>
                <th>Feature</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: features">
                <tr>
                    <td><select data-bind="options: $root.featuresList, value: feature, optionsText:'description'"></select></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: feature().description"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: feature().price"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeFeature">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <a href="#" data-bind="click: addNewFeature">Add a feature</a>
```

I have also put together an example of this.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q6J6a/7/

I feel like I'm missing something small, but it's not jumping out at me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do:

```
self.features.push(new ItemFeature(self.featuresList[0]));
```

rather than:

```
self.features().push(new ItemFeature(self.featuresList[0]));
```

So, you want to call `push` on the observableArray and not the underlying array, so that it notifies subscribers.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Q6J6a/8/